# PHP dropdown list only selecting the last item in list

Tags: php, html

Okay, so I have this page and I want the dropdown to have all of some stuff from a json feed. Just the "label".

Comment: what's this ? `$str = '';` you're setting it to NULL everytime.

Comment: If there is no such thing as $str = ''; it will be undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="items">  
<?php
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json"),true);
$str = '';
foreach($arr as $item) {

$label = $item['label'];       
$str .= "<tr><td style='text-align: center !important;'><b>Name:</b> $label</td>";
echo "<option class=\"selection\" value=\"$label\">$label</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: try again, i edited it. Also you should figure things out from here, it's not that difficult.

Comment: http://cpuploads1.tk/AutoTweet/Items/item.php

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting the contents of $label to the drop down list. At the end of the foreach loop only the last label is stored in $label. Thus, only the last label is being displayed.

Instead, generate the <option>label</option> tags inside the loop and append that to $label. Of course, initialize $label with an empty string before entering the loop.